# Markertype of scatter points in Matlab based on condition

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the following data:

```
xData = [4 7 2 1 2 8 7 1 1 3];
yData = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];

P = [5 10 4 2 7 3 8 1 9 3];
```

I want to use a different markertype based on P. If the corresponding element in P<5 then `'o'` and if P>5 then `'^'`. I know how to do this based on colour (although I don't actually know how to specify what colours to use?) but can this be done with markertype?

```
scatter(xData,yData,70,P>5)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do 2 scatter plots with less and more:

```
xData = [4 7 2 1 2 8 7 1 1 3];
yData = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
P = [5 10 4 2 7 3 8 1 9 3];

x_less = xData(P < 5);
x_more = xData(P >= 5);
y_less = yData(P < 5);
y_more = yData(P >= 5);

figure;
scatter(x_less, y_less, 20, 'r', 'o')
hold on
scatter(x_more, y_more, 20, 'b', '^')
```

This will give you an example like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you tell me why this isn't working: `scatter(x_less, y_less, 20, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 0 0.8008],'o');
hold on;
scatter(x_more, y_more, 20, 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'MarkerFaceColor',[1 0.6 0],'^')`

Comment: @user2861089 what error is it throwing? Is it to do with the color? You need a Mx3 long array for the color.

Comment: @user2861089 actually it looks like you havn't added a color argument which you need. Look at the documentation for scatter [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I thought `'MarkerEdgeColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 0 0.8008]` was right? It works when I don't use the markertype argument...

Comment: @user2861089 Oh ok, yeah, simple fix. Just put the marker type before the Edge and Face color arguments.